# Pacman game: checking and updating 2d array valid positions - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm creating the game "Pacman" only with Javascript.

I need to solve this problem where I'm stuck, I hope some of you guys can help me to check where I'm wrong. Please note I can only use Javascript.

I combined this on a html file to show what's the JS code doing, but we shall focus on the javascript code, first of course I'm interested the game to work. So if you want, ignore the html part.

Please take note I'm rather new programming Javascript and I might use weird ideas.

**The game board**

I need to create "Pacman Game" on a game board array of 30x30.

The game board is on a 2D array called "board", it's length is 30. . The elements inside the "board" array are only "0" and "1" elements. The element "1" means a wall, the element "0" means a path.

**The player**

The player, also an array, can move around the map through "0" path. It spawns randomly inside the map. When it spawns it will need to have randomly a valid direction to move and be able to be controled by last_keyboard_direction pressed (up, down, left, right).

This player array will have 4 elements, by order: [row,column,direction,last_keyboard_direction].

**The ghosts**

The ghosts spawn randomly and automatically move straight to a valid path (where 0's are) until they collide with a wall, then change to another valid direction randomly (up, down, left or right).

Each ghost array element are: [row,column,direction]

**What I've done so far?**

- Created the 2D array boardgame: board[30][30]
- Spawn randomly the player "JG" and 3 ghosts "F0", "F1","F2" on correct positions.

**What I'm trying to do now?**

- Create a function to check (after wall collision) if the positions next to the ghosts are valid to move.
- Then, with this valid next positions, fill a temporal array with this valid positions and choose among them randomly (up, down, left or right).
- If valid position is find then set this new value and keep moving straight until collide again.

**Where I'm stuck?**

I'm stuck at the function: checkPosition(). This function will be used when the ghosts spawn and need to move for the first time, then set the valid direction. Also it will be used when the ghost keep going straight to it's already set direction and collides, then it set a new valid direction.

I need to check if the next position of their direction will be valid, and if not then search for a new valid one and choose only one randomly. The searched valid one's will be saved temporarily to the variable: valid = [];

- When the function finds a valid next position pushes it to the temporary array "valid". For example if the ghost going straight collide with a number "1" it will check for a new valid direction to go straight until it collides again.
- Example: if it can go up and down it will save this on valid[], ending up filled like this: valid[up,down].
- Then a new variable called "direction" will choose it randomly among all elements inside the "valid" array: var direccio = valid[Math.floor(Math.random() * valid.length)]; and finally set the new valid direction to the ghost.

**PLEASE NOTE:**

- The game speed movement will be every 1 second. (speed is not set in this code yet)
- The code don't try to record last arrow key pressed yet.
- Path are number "0", walls are number "1".
- Spawn ghosts and player in random positions, not required in the center
- HTML code is not important, only for your understanding of the code

The code is comented, please check specially the checkPosition() array and how to update the ghosts arrays with its new valid positions.

**ALL CODE:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PACMAN</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <table id="table" cellpadding=4 border="0" style="width:50%;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle" style="align:center">

        <tr>
            <th> 0</th>
            <th> 1</th>
            <th> 2</th>
            <th> 3</th>
            <th> 4</th>
            <th> 5</th>
            <th> 6</th>
            <th> 7</th>
            <th> 8</th>
            <th> 9</th>
            <th>10</th>
            <th>11</th>
            <th>12</th>
            <th>13</th>
            <th>14</th>
            <th>15</th>
            <th>16</th>
            <th>17</th>
            <th>18</th>
            <th>19</th>
            <th>20</th>
            <th>21</th>
            <th>22</th>
            <th>23</th>
            <th>24</th>
            <th>25</th>
            <th>26</th>
            <th>27</th>
            <th>28</th>
            <th>29</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>

        var board = [];
        //GHOSTS, VALUES: [row, column, direction] //set randomly
        var ghost1 = [0, 0, 0];
        var ghost2 = [0, 0, 0];
        var ghost3 = [0, 0, 0];
        //PLAYER, VALUES: [row, column, direction, last_keyboard_direction] //set randomly except last_keyboard_direction
        var player = [0, 0, 0, 0];


        board[0]=      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[1]=      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[2]=      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[3]=      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[4]=      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[5]=      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[6]=      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[7]=      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[8]=      [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[9]=      [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[10]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[11]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[12]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[13]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[14]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[15]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[16]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[17]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[18]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
        board[19]=     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[20]=     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[21]=     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[22]=     [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[23]=     [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
        board[24]=     [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1];
        board[25]=     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[26]=     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[27]=     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
        board[28]=     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1];
        board[29]=     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];


        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        }

        var row_ghost = [];
        var column_ghost = [];

        function generateGhosts() {
            var comptador = 0;
                do {
                    var row = getRandomInt(0, 29);
                    var column = getRandomInt(0, 29);
                    var random_position = board[row][column];
                    if (random_position === 0) {

                        board[row][column] = "F" + comptador;

                        row_ghost.push(row);
                        column_ghost.push(column);

                        document.write("GHOST " + (comptador) + " ACTUAL POSITION:: " + "ROW: " + row + " COLUMN: " + column + " VALUE: " + random_position);
                        document.write(" </br> ");


                        comptador++;

                    }
                } while (comptador < 3) //creates 3 ghosts on valid positions
        }

        function generatePlayer() {
            player = 0;
                do {
                    var row = getRandomInt(0, 29);
                    var column = getRandomInt(0, 29);
                    var random_position = board[row][column];
                    if (random_position === 0) {
                        player++;
                        board[row][column] = "JG";

                        document.write("PLAYER " + (player) + " ACTUAL POSITION:: " + "ROW: " + row + " COLUMN: " + column + " VALUE: " + random_position);
                        document.write(" </br> ");
                    }
                } while (player < 1) //creates one player

        }

        //This next function will need to set a new random valid direction in case the ghost can go straight anymore to it's actual set direction
        function checkPosition() {
            //Check new next positions
            for (i = 0; i < row_ghost.length; i++) {

                var valid = [];

                //CHECKING NEW VALID POSITIONS IF !== 1 then is valid for a new.
                //MY MAIN PROBLEM IS HERE INSIDE THE "IF" CONDITIONALS. YOU CAN TEST document.write("valid");, it just enters all if's all pushes all positions as valid.
                //I know I'm comparing the wrong way. Need to take the element inside this row_ghost and column_ghost position but I dont know how.
                if (((row_ghost[i]) - 1) && (column_ghost[i]) !== 1){
                    //It can go up ^
                    valid.push("up");
                }

                if (((row_ghost[i]) + 1) && (column_ghost[i]) !== 1){
                    //It can go down
                    valid.push("down");
                }

                if ((row_ghost[i] && ((column_ghost[i]) - 1)) !== 1){
                    //It can go left <
                    valid.push("left");
                }

                if ((row_ghost[i] && ((column_ghost[i]) + 1)) !== 1){
                    //It can go right >
                    valid.push("right");
                }

                //Once we checked the possible new valid positions, with the array direction we choose only ONE ELEMENT RANDOMLY
                var direction = valid[Math.floor(Math.random() * valid.length)];

                rowValid = []; //Set a new array to save the next row valid position for each player
                columnValid = []; //Set a new array to save the next column valid position for each player

                //ONLY ONE "direction" WILL BE SENDED BELOW, chosed randomly

                if (direction === "up") {
                    //up ^
                    rowValid = (row_ghost[i] - 1);
                    columnValid = column_ghost[i];
                }

                if (direction === "down"){
                    //down v
                    rowValid = (row_ghost[i] + 1);
                    columnValid = column_ghost[i];
                }

                if (direction === "left"){
                    //left <
                    rowValid = row_ghost[i];
                    columnValid = (column_ghost[i] - 1);
                }

                if (direction === "right"){
                    //right >
                    rowValid = row_ghost[i];
                    columnValid = (column_ghost[i] + 1);
                }

                document.write("NEXT POSITION OF GHOST:::: " + i + ":::: ROW " + rowValid + " - COLUMN " + columnValid);document.write(" Next direction is: " +direction + " ///");
                document.write("/// Next valid positions taken from this gost were: " + valid + ")"); //As you can see it pushes all positions as valid
                document.write("</br>");
                valid = []; //We empty the array for future checkings
            }
        }


        generateGhosts(); //Generate 3 ghosts on valid positions.
        generatePlayer(); //Generate one player on a valid position.

        document.write("</br>");
        document.write("FUTURE PATHS:");
        document.write("</br></br>");

        checkPosition();



        //==============PRINT TABLE HTML==============//
        table = document.getElementById("table");
        for(var i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
           // create a new row
           var newRow = table.insertRow(table.length);
           for(var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
           {
               // create a new cell
               var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);

               // add value to the cell
               cell.innerHTML = board[i][j];
           }
       }
        //==============TABLE PRINTED==============//

    </script>
```

**MAIN PROBLEMATIC CODE:**

Please note the: row_ghost.push(row); and column_ghost.push(column);
It will be used on other function checkPosition();

```
function generateGhosts() {
            var comptador = 0;
                do {
                    var row = getRandomInt(0, 29);
                    var column = getRandomInt(0, 29);
                    var random_position = board[row][column];
                    if (random_position === 0) {

                        board[row][column] = "F" + comptador;

                        row_ghost.push(row);
                        column_ghost.push(column);
                        comptador++;

                    }
                } while (comptador < 3) //creates 3 ghosts on valid positions
        }

//This next function will need to set a new random valid direction in case the ghost can go straight anymore to it's actual set direction
        function checkPosition() {
            //Check new next positions
            for (i = 0; i < row_ghost.length; i++) {

                var valid = [];

                if (((row_ghost[i]) - 1) && (column_ghost[i]) !== 1){
                    //It can go up ^
                    valid.push("up");
                }

                if (((row_ghost[i]) + 1) && (column_ghost[i]) !== 1){
                    //It can go down
                    valid.push("down");
                }

                if ((row_ghost[i] && ((column_ghost[i]) - 1)) !== 1){
                    //It can go left <
                    valid.push("left");
                }

                if ((row_ghost[i] && ((column_ghost[i]) + 1)) !== 1){
                    //It can go right >
                    valid.push("right");
                }

                //Once we checked the possible new valid positions, with the array direction we choose only ONE ELEMENT RANDOMLY
                var direction = valid[Math.floor(Math.random() * valid.length)];

                rowValid = []; //Set a new array to save the next row valid position for each player
                columnValid = []; //Set a new array to save the next column valid position for each player

                //ONLY ONE "direction" WILL BE SENDED BELOW, chosed randomly

                if (direction === "up") {
                    //up ^
                    rowValid = (row_ghost[i] - 1);
                    columnValid = column_ghost[i];
                }

                if (direction === "down"){
                    //down v
                    rowValid = (row_ghost[i] + 1);
                    columnValid = column_ghost[i];
                }

                if (direction === "left"){
                    //left <
                    rowValid = row_ghost[i];
                    columnValid = (column_ghost[i] - 1);
                }

                if (direction === "right"){
                    //right >
                    rowValid = row_ghost[i];
                    columnValid = (column_ghost[i] + 1);
                }

                valid = []; //We empty the array for future checkings
            }
        }
```

Comment: You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not exactly related, but you can't call `document.write` in an event handler function. The function call would open a new document, and wipe everything out of the current document. Use console for debugging.

Comment: @Teemu yes, it's only to understand what's going on with the code and what variables values are being used in the functions. Not for the final use to play, take it only for reference. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, only that console is much more handy when trying " _to understand what's going on_".

Comment: Or the debugger. This is a pretty big wall of text—I’d recommend paring it down to the essentials.

Comment: Noted, @Teemu and Dave Thanks for your advise :)